# How to set drawable left for a expandable list group

Tags: android

I have a list view, in which one item of the listview is expandable one and i want to set drawable left icons for all items of listview. But for the item expandable i don't know how to do it, can anyone help me?

here is my code

```
private class HelpListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

private Holder holder;
private Context context;

public HelpListAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (view == null) {
        holder = new Holder();
        if (position == 3) {
            view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.list_item_with_expandable_new, null);
            holder.expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.expand_list);
            holder.containerList = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.container_expandable_list);
        } else {
            view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.list_item_text, null);
            holder.textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
    }

    if (position != 3) {
        holder.textView.setText(mHelpLabels.get(position));
        Drawable[] iconLeft = {Util.getCustomDrawableColor(getActivity(),R.drawable.ic_favorite_18dp,R.color.beco_logout_red, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP),
                Util.getCustomDrawableColor(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_checkin_18dp, R.color.beco_logout_red, PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN),
                Util.getCustomDrawableColor(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_faq, R.color.beco_white, PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN),
                Util.getCustomDrawableColor(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_feedback, R.color.beco_white, PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN),
                Util.getCustomDrawableColor(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_feedback, R.color.beco_white, PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN),
                Util.getCustomDrawableColor(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_share_app, R.color.beco_white, PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN),
                Util.getCustomDrawableColor(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_privacy, R.color.beco_white, PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN),
                Util.getCustomDrawableColor(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_terms, R.color.beco_white, PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN),
                Util.getCustomDrawableColor(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_faq, R.color.beco_white, PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN),
                Util.getCustomDrawableColor(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_beco_settings, R.color.beco_white, PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN),
                Util.getCustomDrawableColor(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_beco_settings, R.color.beco_white, PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN),

        };
        holder.textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(iconLeft[position], null, null, null);

    } else {
        holder.expandableListView.setAdapter(new ExpandableListAdapter(context, mHelpLabels.get(position), view));
        holder.expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener((parentExpand, v, groupPosition, id) -> {
            setListViewHeight(parentExpand, groupPosition);
            return false;
        });
    }

    return view;
}

class Holder {
    TextView textView;
    ExpandableListView expandableListView;
    LinearLayout containerList;
}

private void setListViewHeight(ExpandableListView listView, int group) {

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter = (ExpandableListAdapter) listView.getExpandableListAdapter();
    int height = 0;
    int groupCount = 0;
    int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    View groupItem = listAdapter.getGroupView(groupCount, false, null, listView);
    groupItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    height += groupItem.getMeasuredHeight();

    if (((listView.isGroupExpanded(groupCount)) && (groupCount != group))
            || ((!listView.isGroupExpanded(groupCount)) && (groupCount == group))) {
        for (int j = 0; j < listAdapter.getChildrenCount(groupCount); j++) {
            View listItem = listAdapter.getChildView(groupCount, j, false, null, listView);
            listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            height += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
    }
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();

    if (height < 10)
        height = 200;
    params.height = height;
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}

class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    Context context;
    String title;
    View viewParent;

    ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, String title, View view) {
        this.context = context;
        this.title = title;
        this.viewParent = view;
    }

    @Override
    public String getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return mContactLabels.get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_text, null);
        }
        Drawable[] iconLeft = {Util.getCustomDrawableColor(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_email, R.color.beco_icon_tint_color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP),
                Util.getCustomDrawableColor(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_phone_black, R.color.beco_icon_tint_color, PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN)};

        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        textView.setText(mContactLabels.get(childPosition));
        textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(iconLeft[childPosition], null, null, null);
        textView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            switch (childPosition) {
                case 0:
                    Intent intentEmail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                    intentEmail.setData(Uri.fromParts("mailto", mContactLabels.get(childPosition), null));
                    intentEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Contact beCo");
                    startActivity(intentEmail);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Intent intentCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                    intentCall.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + mContactLabels.get(childPosition)));
                    startActivity(intentCall);
                    break;
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return mContactLabels.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return mContactLabels.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_text, null);
        }
        TextView contact = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        contact.setText(title);
        Drawable iconLeft = Util.getCustomDrawableColor(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_contact_blue, R.color.beco_white, PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN);
        contact.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null,null,iconLeft,null);

        LinearLayout border = (LinearLayout) viewParent.findViewById(R.id.container_expandable_list);

        Drawable iconRight = Util.getCustomDrawableColor(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black, R.color.beco_black, PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN);

        if (isExpanded) {
            border.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
            iconRight = Util.getCustomDrawableColor(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_up_black, R.color.beco_black, PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN);
            contact.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.beco_primary));
            contact.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, iconRight, null);
        } else {
            border.setBackgroundResource(0);
            contact.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.beco_label_color));
            contact.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, iconRight, null);
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: find out the parent and child views for the list view and add drwable left in xml to that

Comment: I have done it. But not getting drarwable icon for expandable list.Drawable iconLeft = Util.getCustomDrawableColor(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_contact_blue, R.color.beco_white, PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN);
        contact.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null,null,iconLeft,null);

Comment: did you find the parent view

Comment: contact.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null,null,ic‌​onLeft,null);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.
It was my mistake. It was due to the groupIndicator icon of the ExpandableListView.
I set groupIndicator as null.
That is in **list_item_with_expandable_new.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container_expandable_list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expand_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:groupIndicator="@null"
    android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="@dimen/dp1"
    />
```

Which solved my issue